# Unit test if method deletes a source data file

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Super noob with unit testing...

I have a method that processes and then deletes an input file.  How can I unit test the if the file actually gets deleted?  I understand it's a bad practice to do actual file IO during a unit test.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an absolute rule - if you're class lives on the periphery i.e. interfaces with some external subsystem (in this case the filesystem), then the right way to test it is with the real subsystem.

The GOOS book deems these tests as "integration tests" because these tests test whether your class integrates with the external subsystem.

The consumers of this class can abstract away the file system via an interface exposed by this class.

My question/acid test for this decision is - what is the primary responsibility of this class ?

- if it is accessing the filesystem, then I need to write integration tests
- if it is not, then use a mock and concentrate on the real responsibility. e.g. act as a customer repository (which "uses/delegates" to a dependency to deal with the filesystem).

Comment: +1 for mocking out the file system if it's not the class's responsibility. The number of times we've ended up having to delete files over web services etc. when they used to be local is insane; keep this easy to change. A stubbed file system is probably simple enough to test by inspection. Acceptance tests or scenarios (not quite the same as integration tests) can also be used to check what happened to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Have the method do a System.IO.File.Copy() of the source file and then use the copy to do your testing. Hopefully, your code is setup to specify which file to process.